# How new relic ruby vm show threads per instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, newrelic, puma, newrelic-platform

I have 2 instances of my app running, I have set threads per worker to max 15 but in a new relic thread per instance count goes max to 16.5 how is this possible?
I am using puma as a app server.

Comment: Did you find out?